# MVC view not binding inputs in for loop if loop contains if statement to control input rendering

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view that creates a number of input boxes based on the length of a view model property of type `List<decimal>`.

I use a for loop with index to bind the inputs to the list. This works fine, and user inputted values get passed to POST method ok. The following code works fine (e.g. 3 inputs with values of 1, 2 and 3 then `MyList = [1,2,3]`):

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count; i++)
{
    <input asp-for="MyList[i]" type="text">
}
```

However, I need to set the disabled state of the first input box to "disabled". If I add an if statement as follows, the binding doesn't work and the MyList property is empty with count of zero. (e.g. 2 inputs - first one is read only -
 with values of 2 and 3 then `MyList = []`. I pre-populate first input box in controller with value of 1 so I would hope to get `MyList = [1,2,3]` but I don't)

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count; i++)
      if (i == 0)
      {
          <input asp-for="MyList[i]" type="text" disabled="disabled">
      }
      else
      {
          <input asp-for="MyList[i]" type="text">
      }
}
```

Code has been boiled down to the minimum for brevity

Any ideas why this if statement is killing the binding, or how to get round this? Thanks for reading!

EDIT: I have tried rendering the first input before and outside the loop and then starting the loop at index of 1, but the same problem occurs.

UPDATE: I can easily set the disabled state to true by using jQuery but this kills the property too. So any bound input that is disabled is clearing MyList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` requires that collection indexers start an zero and be consecutive (unless you add a input for the collection indexer).

Disabled controls do no submit a value, so when you disable the first input, the first item has an indexer of `1`, not `0`, so model binding fails.

A simple way to solve this would be to make the input readonly

```
<input asp-for="MyList[i]" type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

Another option is to include a hidden input for the collection indexer which allows collection to be bound where the indexer is not zero-based and consecutive.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count; i++)
      if (i == 0)
      {
          <input asp-for="MyList[i]" type="text" disabled="disabled">
      }
      else
      {
          <input asp-for="MyList[i]" type="text">
      }
      <input type="hidden" name="MyList.Index" value="@i" />
}
```

But note that in that case, the collection will be missing the first item (because the value of the disabled input will not be submitted).

Comment: A solution and an explanation of why my code didn't work. Perfect, thank you very much :o)